# AngularJS - Improving service call and data binding performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-services, angular-http

I have an Angular service that goes away to retrieve a pretty big JSON file (nearly 10,000 lines).

The problem i am facing, is that it is taking some time to bind the data to the front-end (as expected).

Sample controller:

```
$scope.dataLoaded = false;

serviceReport.getData( function (data) {
    $scope.data1 = data.data1;
    $scope.data2 = data.data2;
    $scope.data3 = data.data3;
    $scope.data4 = data.data4;
    $scope.data5 = data.data5;
    $scope.data6 = data.data6;
    $scope.data7 = data.data7;
    $scope.data8 = data.data8;
    $scope.data9 = data.data9;
    $scope.data10 = data.data10;
    $scope.data11 = data.data11;
    $scope.data12 = data.data12;
    $scope.data13 = data.data13;
    $scope.data14 = data.data14;
    $scope.data15 = data.data15;
    $scope.data16 = data.data16;
    $scope.data17 = data.data17;

    $scope.dataLoaded = true;
});
```

Service:

```
app.factory('serviceReport', function($http) {
    return {
        getData: function(value,done) {
            $http.get('data.json', {
                })
            .success(function(data) { 
                done(data);
            })
            .error(function(error) {
                alert('An error occured');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I have ng-cloak on my HTML element, when dataLoaded = true, this is removed as it indicates the data is available to be displayed.

How can i improve the service call/data bind? Would splitting the call help?

Comment: Why don't yu show a loader while it's loading the data ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem - i currently am showing a loader.. I guess what i am asking is, can i display data1,2,3,4 ASAP as they are at the top of the page and then load the rest?

Comment: You can, but the delay is probably due to fetching the data, so other than splitting up the request, there doesn't seem to be much more you can do.

Comment: I am thinking of a server-side fix, and a client-side fix, you are trying to fix this entirely on browser-side?, or a solution involving the server is acceptable too ?

Comment: @dseminara - browser-side for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

Server-side solution would be to reduce the size of the response and make more requests with smaller responses. Do you actually need the whole response at start? You have to be aware that binding the whole response will generate many watchers, which will slow down all subsequent digests.

Client-side solution would be to bind the response part by part in a loop as a callback parameter for $scope.$apply() or even $timeout().